# How can i show a default date in input type date in HTML?

Tags: html, date, input

When I use `type="text"` then it shows the date in input box but it doesn't show dropdown calendar but if set it to `type="date"` it doesn't display calendar for input.

Answer (score 2):

The `date` field only accepts values in the `YYYY-MM-DD` format:

```html
<label><input type="date" value="2016-05-26"> Format YYYY-MM-DD</label><br />
<label><input type="date" value="26.05.2016"> Format DD.MM.YYYY</label>
```

It will display the date in your locale, but it will still be internally be `YYYY-MM-DD`.

Comment: Thank You! But how to use it along with ng-model                                   <input placeholder="--Date--" type="date" value="2016-05-29" ng-model = "start_date" required="">

Answer (score 0):

Use the `value` attribute to define default values.

`<input type="date" value="2016-05-29">`

Comment: I am not being able to use it along with ng-model                                               <input placeholder="--Date--" type="date" value="2016-05-29" ng-model = "start_date" required="">

Comment: Why not just use ng-model to represent a default value? That way it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Try This It will helps You .

```
<input type="date" id="datt1" >

<script type="text/javascript">
var d1 = new Date();
var y1= d1.getFullYear();
var m1 = d1.getMonth()+1;
if(m1<10)
    m1="0"+m1;
var dt1 = d1.getDate();
if(dt1<10)
dt1 = "0"+dt1;
var d2 = y1+"-"+m1+"-"+dt1;
document.getElementById("datt1").value=d2;
</script>
```

and You Can also try 
always use ( - ) as a separator in date formate while print in value attribute in html input type date   .